# Yii2 pretty URL returning not found 404

Tags: apache, ubuntu, yii2

(I purposely titled it this way because the other suggestions I have seen in stackoverflow so far either do not apply in my case or do not work.)

I am in the process of moving a working Yii2 app from an Ubuntu 14.04 VM to a 22.04 VM, which I built separately instead of going through various OS upgrade steps to get to the current version.  The PHP version is the same on both VMs. The pretty URL **http://(server)/site/login** returns a 404. The Apache2 access log shows:

```
192.168.130.212 - - [06/Mar/2023:18:30:03 -1000] "GET /site/login HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0"
192.168.130.212 - - [06/Mar/2023:18:30:03 -1000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1450 "http://beretania/site/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0"
```

Nothing in the error log.  I tried as much as possible to duplicate the server configuration. And the code itself, which is managed in GitHub, should be identical.

From config

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
```

.htaccess

```
# Requires FollowSymLinks to work; also turn on the REWRITE engine
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# Unless explicit file or director exists, redirect all requests to Yii entry script
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>

AddType application/octet-stream .txt
```

The enabled site in both cases is called dbos.

Here is the dbos.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jmdemoor@localhost
    ServerName beretania
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dbos/web
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/dbos/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Pertinent except from apache2.conf (which I assume is overridden by the enabled site dbos.conf anyway):

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
...
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

This is what I get:

[image: 404 result screen shot]

The same url with the production VM works fine.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Joe

Comment: Did you check that `mod_rewrite` is installed and enabled? The rewrite rules in `.htaccess` are inside `IfModule` directives. If `mod_rewrite` is missing these blocks will be ignored and they won't cause any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Michal Hynčica.  mod_rewrite was not enabled.

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Solved.